# Confused about a proof involving the uniqueness of Taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the theorem and proof that I am confused about:

[image]

I have a couple questions about this "proof":

**1.)** First, let me know whether I am interpreting the uniqueness argument correctly. We take some point $z_0 \in D'$ and create the stated contour $C$. Since these two functions are both analytic in this region, we know that they have uniformly convergent Taylor series. However, since they coincide in this region they have all of the same derivatives and hence coefficients, and therefore they are the *same* by uniqueness of Taylor series. Yes? So, I am now confused about the characteristics that $D'$ must have. Clearly it does not have to be open, since $\Gamma$ is just a curve, but can it just be a point? Why or why not?

**2.)** I do not quite see how the extended domain argument is intuitively clear. What if $D$ is disjoint and these two functions only coincide on *one* of the portions? Once you have filled up the starting section, how can you jump to another with this argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You're correct in your bit about uniqueness of taylor series. As for $D'$, clearly $\Gamma$ cannot be just a point: there are plenty of functions that agree on a single point but aren't the same! ($e^{-z}$ and $e^z$, for instance, agree at $z=0$.) For this argument to work they must agree on an arc (i.e., the 'subportion' mentioned has some curve in it).

2) A domain is defined as a **connected** open subset of $\Bbb C$. Note that $D$ is a domain. There's no 'jumping around'.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the answer! I figured that it could not just be a point; intuitively I now see there would have to be neighboring points that also agree in order to pin them down to have the same derivatives, and thanks for that example. Ah, connected, of course.

Comment: @Daniel Just so you know, if an answer resolves your question, you should accept it (checkmark below the upvotes/downvotes) to take it off the unanswered questions list. (Of course, if mine doesn't answer your question, don't accept it.)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'm fairly new to the forum. Will do.